# TCSH bitwise | operator

Tags: tcsh, arithmetic

How do I use the bitwise logical-or operator, |, in tcsh?

I enter

```
@ y = 1001; @ z = 0110;
@ x = $y|$z
110: Command not found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really want to do this in tcsh only? Csh and its derivative tcsh have [many such quirks](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot). You are better off with another shell like bash etc.

In this particular case, it appears that throwing in a pair of parenthesis keeps tcsh happy. This is also documented in the tcsh manual:

> expr may contain the operators `*`, `+`, etc.,  as  in  C.   If
>   expr  contains  `<`,  `>`, `&` or `|` then at least that part of
>   expr must be placed within `()`.

```
mint13:~> echo $version
tcsh 6.17.06 (Astron) 2011-04-15 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,rh,nd,color,filec
mint13:~> @ y = 1001; @ z = 0110;
mint13:~> @ x = $y|$z
110: Command not found.
mint13:~> @ x = ($y|$z)
mint13:~> echo $x
1007
```

You might already be aware of this — tcsh is reading 1001 and 0110 as decimal numbers. I don't know how to make it understand binary numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's becoming increasingly apparent that conventional wisdom that tcsh is inconsistent is true. Will be switching soon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about how to declare binary numbers; but your syntax is wrong.

The '@' had its own expression parser and somehow it confused with the primary parser if the expression is not parenthesised. According the man-page it need spaces in several cases include the bitwise operators. I suggest use spaces everywhere since it had many bugs there.

This will work smoothly:

```
@ y = 1001; @ z = 0110;
@ x = ( $y | $z ); echo $x
```

Notice that, like C, number that starts with 0, are octals, so $z value is 72 in decimal.

Octals and hexadecimals are used because they ca representing the binary numbers exactly. An octal digit is representing 3 binary digits.

```
binary <--> octal
   000         0
   001         1
   010         2
   011         3
   100         4
   101         5
   110         6
   111         7
```

If y and z values that you wrote are in binary, this is the correct form  (by using octals)

```
@ y = 011; @z = 006;
@ x = ( $y | $z ); echo $x
15
```

There is another solution, use whatever command-line calculator you want by using back-quoted expression. I suggest to try [**calc**](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/calc/), **bc** or **awk** with this order.

Example with calc:

```
set x = `calc '0b1001 | 0b110'`; echo $x
15
```

15 (dec) = 017 (oct) = 0xF (hex) = 0b1111 (bin)